# Why can't I change keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: 11.10, shortcuts, shortcut-keys

I can bring the window up no problem:

[image]

The shortcut I want to modify is selected, I press on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, and nothing happens. I tried pressing and holding 5 seconds. Nothing happened. Ever heard of this? Can anyone reproduce this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to click onto `Disabled` with your mouse at first, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>.

[image: new shortcut]

Comment: Vote this comment up if you find the instructions misleading. Thanks for the tip Jakob :)